# Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring Boot and I might be doing some silly mistake so Appologies in advance for such question.
I'm trying to write POST API which accept following JSON :

```
{
  "id" : null,
  "a": 1.3,
  "b": "somestring",
   "mapJson" : 
    { 
        "monday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00", 
        "tuesday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00",
        "wednesday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00",
        "thursday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00",
        "friday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00",
        "saturday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00",
        "sunday" : "10:00-12:00/n14:00-18:00"
    },
    "list" : ["cc","paytm","debit"]
}
```

Consider following DTO class , **AbcDTO** :

```
package com.abb.dto;
import java.util.List;
import com.abb.entities.OpeningHrs;
import lombok.Data;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Data
public class AbcDTO {

    private Long id;
    private Double a;
    private String b;
    private MapJson mapJson;
    private List<String> list;

}
```

**OpeningHrs** is Class for mapping Json Map structure,

```
package com.abb.entities;
import lombok.Data;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Data
public class MapJson {

    private String monday;
    private String tuesday;
    private String wednesday;
    private String thursday;
    private String friday;
    private String saturday;
    private String sunday;

}
```

**AbcController** which have Post API :

```
package com.abb.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.abb.dto.AbcDTO;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/abc")
@GetMapping(value="/{id}",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public class HotelController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/xyz", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody AbcDTO registerHotel(@RequestBody AbcDTO aaa) {

       System.out.println(aaa.toString());
       return aaa; 
   // I'm not able to map JSON into this Object
    }

}
```

Please find following Responce I'm getting is :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1509193409948,
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/abc/xyz"
}
```

Comment: When you send your json, do you add the header Content-Type: application/json ?

Comment: I have already added Content-Type: application/json in request header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `POST` request doesn't work because Spring doesn't know what kind of data it's expecting. So you will need to tell spring that you're expecting `APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` so it knows how to process. `consumes=` will, as you probably guessed, tell Spring what the incoming `POST` body context type.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "xyz", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody AbcDTO registerHotel(@RequestBody AbcDTO aaa) {

    System.out.println(aaa.toString());
    return aaa; 
    // I'm not able to map JSON into this Object
}
```

With PostMapping

```java
@PostMapping(value = "xyz", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody AbcDTO registerHotel(@RequestBody AbcDTO aaa) {

   System.out.println(aaa.toString());
   return aaa; 
   // I'm not able to map JSON into this Object
}
```

As you can see I have also added something else called, `produces=` this will instruct Spring how to format the response body of that request. So frontend receives `JSON` formatted body, not just random text.

Comment: Thanks , I missed that consumes parameter. but after adding it, it still **not working**

Comment: I've added `PostMapping`, could you see if that works? Could toy also try removing the `GetMapping` of the `Class` as well, that might be blocking the entire `Class` as the request is `Post`.

Comment: Assuming you've also removed the `GetMapping` from the Class as well. Has the error changed at all? And what tool are you using to send request?

Comment: Yes, I have removed GetMapping from the Class and I'm using ARC and PostMan Both to send request, while Content-Type is set as Application/Json and request JSON is in Body.

Comment: @Mayur Could you try removing the `/` of `/xyz`, that is the only thing I can think of now. Other than, the only thing I can think of is the use of `Get` method on PostMan` instead `Post`; but I highly doubt that's the case.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that I didn't specify public getters in response class (analog of your AbcDTO class). So there were nothing to get to serialize and return to client.

Comment: This helped me. I had converted the response object from a Java Record to a regular POJO class but had kept the getters in record-style. Fixed by adding a "get" Prefix to each one.

Answer (score 3):

In my case helped this in pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In your case I guess that your service produce XML? That was also the case for me but I also had to configure a message converter:

    `@Override  
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I just spent half a day on this error, and finally discovered that Spring's ContentNegotiationConfigurer by default favours the *path extension* if it's present. I had this particular mapping:

```
@PostMapping(value="/convert/{fileName:.+}",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<String, String> convert(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestBody String data) {
   // Do conversion
}
```

Now when I posted to this controller with a filename "outputfile.pdf", Spring would simply assume the response had to be PDF, completely ignoring the "produces" parameter for the PostMapping.

The problem can be fixed fixed with ContentNegotiationConfigurer.favorPathExtension(false). As of Spring web 5.3 this should be the default, but still isn't.