# Spring ExceptionHandler No acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As an api consumer, given header “Accept: application/xml”, I would like to receive 406 response in such a format:

```
{
    “status”: ${responseCode}
    “Message”: ${whyHasItHappened}
}
```

In the case of `ExceptionHandler`, I initially used `ObjectMapper` and returned String, but I was told to use it (ObjectMapper) as a last resort. When I return an Error, if I provide the 'application/xml' header, an exception is thrown, but I don't receive the response body in Postman.

RepoController class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class RepoController {

    private final RepoServiceImpl repoService;

    public RepoController(RepoServiceImpl repoService) {
        this.repoService = repoService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Flux<ResponseRepo> getReposByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        return repoService.getReposInfo(username);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public Error handleInvalidAcceptHeader(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
        return new Error(e.getStatusCode(), "Type not acceptable");
    }

}
```

Exception thrown

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation
```

Comment: Add the type of the exception to handle as a parameter of the @ExceptionHandler annotation, not as method parameter.  Like so: @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaNotAcceptableException.class)

Comment: @gbuys I think the problem is that given `Accept` header of "application/xml" it cannot return Error, because with String type it works just fine. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Make sure xml is supported see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196721/1527469

Comment: @robertos Was you able to solve this? I have the same problem, except it doesn't work even if I return a String.